config the file init.py to run manim
in the file init.py, it said that from animation.creation import * is not found.
How can I find the file  and the file "c\Python312\Srcipts\manim.exe_main_.py" on vscode?
What version of python should I use?
how to set up manim environment?
[maim picture]
(https://i.sstatic.net/0kl8esvC.png)

Please provide more debugging details. In particular, that means providing a [mre] and a full error traceback, both as code-fenced text rather than an image.
